# How to make 1 + 1 = 2 instead of 1 + 1 = 11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add the number mathematically, but it keeps adding the number after it.

It takes the id number (begen), then it gets the number inside another div (kacbegen).

```
var begen = $(this).attr('id');
var kacbegen = $("#math" + begen).text();
var toplam = (kacbegen + 1);

alert(toplam);
```

However, when doing the math (toplam), it alerts all the numbers.How to add the number mathematically ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert it to number via adding a `+`:

```
var toplam = (+kacbegen + 1);
```

> ### [Unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)
>
> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't already.

Comment: This I didn't know!, will this method work only for `integer` or `floating` numbers also?

Comment: quite true but as far as numbers are concerned this would do @Bharadwaj

Comment: Clearest answer ever. Thanks!

Comment: this will call `parseFloat` internally? because `parseFloat` will convert in weird way for some floating values.

Comment: @user198989 And by the way, neither protect from getting a `NaN`, so make sure you handle this case as well.

Comment: @Bharadwaj I was wrong `+('1x')` would give `NaN` whereas   `parseFloat('1x')` would give `1`, so they're not the same after all, so `parseFloat` is safer, in a way.

Comment: @axelduch hmm, need to try with this method sometime. And thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're working with *Strings* (and thus `a + b` is the concatenation operator) when you want to be working with *Number* (so `x + y` would be addition)

Perform your favorite way to cast *String* to *Number*, e.g. a unary `+x`

```
var kacbegen = +$("#math" + begen).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `parseInt` to convert `kacbegen`, which is a `String` instance, to a `Number`:

```
var begen = $(this).attr('id');
var kacbegen = $("#math" + begen).text();
var toplam = (parseInt(kacbegen) + 1);

alert(toplam);
```

The `+` operator, when used with a `String` on either side, will serve as a concatenation, calling `Number.prototype.toString` on `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the contents to a number:

```
var contents = $("#math" + begen).text();
var kacbegen = parseFloat(contents);
```

Answer (score 1):

You use kacbegen as a string. Please use as a integer use `parseInt(kacbegen) + 1`